# How to set time and date in calender class in Java?

Tags: java, calendar, initialization, java.util.calendar

```
import java.util.*;

enum CITY{ROME,BUDAPEST,PARIS,GREECE,TALIN,AMSTREDAM,VIENNA;}

class Flight{
    private String flightName = "AirBus";
    private int ticketPrice = 50;
    private CITY Destination = CITY.ROME;
    private int numberOfTravellers = 83;
    private int flightDuration = 2;
    Calendar flightTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar flightDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    flightDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2002);
    flightDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
    flightDate.set(Calendar.DAY, 20);
    flightTime.set(Calendar.HOUR,10);
    flightTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    flightTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    private static int goalTicketPrice = 35;
}
```

I am tring to set the Date and time of the flight.
but getting these types of 18 errors.

It gives this error ....

```
<identifier> expected
    flightDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2002);
```

Comment: You should not use the `Calendar` class. It is cumbersome to work with and long outdated. I think you want `ZonedDateTime flightDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2002, 3, 20, 22, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.systemDefault());`. The `ZonedDateTime` class is part of [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: Completely aside: The capital of Estonia is spelled *Tallinn* with double l and double n. Greece is not a city, you may have thought `ATHENS`?